# Moving rectangles one by one (using class and foreach loop)

Tags: c#, xna

I have write codes to move more than one rectangles posted 
here.
[moving rectangles one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415650/moving-rectangles-one-by-one)

However, in order to make my code neat, I rewrote it in such a way below using class and foreach loop. But this time, I can't move them one by one. Any idea to fix it please?
Many thanks in advance.

In my object.cs class:

```
    public bool GetSelected(int x, int y)
    //  public Rectangle GetSelected(List<Rectangle> squares)
    {
        bool GetSelected = false;
        MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

        // Rectangle mousePosition = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 200, 80);

        if (drawRectangle.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y) && (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed))
            {
                GetSelected = true;                
            }            
        return GetSelected;
    }
```

In my code in main.cs, I used the following to move rectangle. However, If I have more than one rectangles, how can I select one rectangle each time if some rectangles are overlap?
Thanks.

```
        foreach (Chemtile chemtile in tiles)
        {

            if (chemtile.GetSelected(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
            {
                chemtile.drawRectangle.X = mouse.X - BoxWidth / 2;
                chemtile.drawRectangle.Y = mouse.Y - BoxHeight / 2;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something call `Hit-Testing`.  Basically loop through your rectangles from the "top" of the screen to the bottom.  The first rectangle that contains the click bounds is the rectangle that was clicked on.  Once you find the first rectangle you should stop searching.

The key to making this work is that the rectangles need to be tested in the top down order that they appear visually on the screen and that you return only the first rectangle that contains the point.

Comment: Hi, Bradley. Thanks for your answer. I am newbie in C#. Is there any example I can study for the Hit-testing algorithm please?

Comment: It looks like you got basics of the hit test in your code already, you just need to refine it a bit.  I generally store the drawn objects in the order that they should be drawn.  Then I have a function called `HitTest` that takes a point and loops backwards through the list of objects and returns the first object that has bounds that contain the point.